# How to pick color that will not be same next to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding a random background color with this code

```
var hue = ['#2dafe9','#5feec3','#fdaf17','#999999','#2b2b2b','#454323','#ab34ef', '#e324e2','#874edf','#18edf4'];
    function getHue(){
        return hue[Math.floor(Math.random() * hue.length)];
    }

    function rainbow(){
        $("header[role='postHeader']").each(function(){
                $(this).css('background-color',getHue());
        });
    }
    rainbow();
```

My question is, how to select a color in order of the array without having to same color next to each other in the result, so the color would follow the array order instead and then if its get to the last array loop back to the first one.

Comment: You either want randomness or sequence. Which one?

Comment: sequence in same order as the array

Comment: Also, "color" has nothing to do with this problem, and it can be abstracted out entirely. The question is about imbuing a certain semantics (yet to be clarified by the OP) on the result of sequential array access. Even Javascript isn't strictly relevant; jQuery certainly isn't.

Comment: Then why do your question and code attempt to use randomness? It's a completely different concept.

Comment: The question is more on how to modify this code that is random to follow the array.

Comment: (Step 1) Remove the code that does random things. (Step 2) Add code that accesses the array in order sequentially.

Comment: http://phrogz.net/tmp/24colors.html

Answer (score 2):

```
function getHue() {
    var t = hue.shift();
    hue.push(t);
    return t;
}
```

This takes the first hue, puts it back on the end of the array, and returns it.

Comment: Note that this approach is much less efficient than the one mentioned by Andrew, changing the Array twice while you actually just want to read from it.

Comment: True, but `rainbow` appears to be a single-use function. Thus the performance difference is negligeable, unless there's forty billion `<header role="postHeader">`s on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Keeps a local var and walks through the array.

```
(function(){
  var idx = 0;
  function getHue(){
    return hue[idx = idx++ % hue.length];
  }
})();
```

Comment: Don't forget to actually apply the modulo to the variable. Or it'll eventually overflow.